# Trying to vertically align icons and divs

Tags: html, css

I'm using [materializecss](http://materializecss.com), and I need help to align the contents vertically center only. I'm not good with CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/Shank09/z0pu0znm/

I've played around with `line-height`, `font-size`, and `margin`.

Here is the image:

[image]

HTML code:

```
   <div class="col s12 m6">
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title">
              <i class="material-icons">business_center</i>
                My List
              <span id="listcount">
                (12)
              </span>
              <i class="material-icons right">search</i>
              <span class="new badge yellow" data-badge-caption="">
                1
              </span>
              <span class="new badge red" data-badge-caption="">
                12
              </span>
              <span class="new badge green" data-badge-caption="">
                1
              </span>
            </span>
```

I'm aiming for:

[image]

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are wanting to align. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I think he means align the three squares with the "My List" title *horizontally*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? https://jsfiddle.net/z0pu0znm/1/

I added an additional parent element around the icons to contain them. They have a `margin-left: auto;` which by itself wouldn't do anything. That's where parent elements comes in.

```
.card .card-content .card-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

This uses [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a great way of quickly aligning a bunch of stuff. In this case `align-items` centers then vertically. I recommend looking in to Flexbox, as it will save you tons of headaches in the long run!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [this is what you want](https://jsfiddle.net/z0pu0znm/4/).

Added CSS:

```
.card .card-content .card-title, .badges, .title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.card .card-content .card-title {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.title > * {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Also added a `.badges` span around your badges + search icon, and a `.title` span around your title text.